# Why won't this JSON file parse into my object with __dict__ = json.load(f)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a json file which contains this text:

```
{"_firstName": "John", "_lastName": "Baker", "_middleName": null, "_mobile": "7609984356", "_education": "Harvard", "_skills": null, "_email": "john@baker.com"}
```

I am trying to load it in to this Python object:

```
class Profile():
    def __init__(self):
        self._firstName = None
        self._lastName = None
        self._middleName = None
        self._mobile = None
        self._education = None
        self._skills = []
        self._email = None
```

I am using:

```
def profileImport(self):
    with open("../tests/profile.json", "r") as f:
        self._prof.__dict__ = json.load(f)
```

the line `self._prof.__dict__ = json.load(f)` is not properly loading the JSON data. I do not get an error from that line, but the object has all None types, indicating that the line didn't successfully load the json data. However, if I use `json.loads()`, I do get the valid json data as a string, which shows me that the proper file is being accessed. Why is `self._prof.__dict__ = json.load(f)` failing to parse the data into my object? I'm using Python 3.6.9.

Comment: why don't you do `prof = Profile(**json.load(f))`

Comment: What is `self._prof`?? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `self._prof` is an instance of the Profile() class shown exactly how it is above. Meaning, that `self._prof` is an instance of that class with all fields set to None. I've passed a brand new `Prof()` into the importer and called `profileImport()` on it.

Comment: @the_endian you're not understanding, **your example isn't reproducible**. Of course, you haven't *provide a complete example*, which is what I'm asking for - a [mcve], but when I try to assign a dict deserialized from the json you've provided to a `Profile` object, it works **as expected**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a a `dataclass` with a class method for this.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
import json


@dataclass
class Profile:
    _firstName: str
    _lastName: str
    _mobile: str
    _education: str
    _email: str
    _skills: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    _middleName: str = ""

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self._skills is None:
            self._skills = []
        if self._middleName is None:
            self._middleName = ""

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, f):
        return cls(**json.load(f))


with open("tmp.json") as f:
    profile = Profile.from_json(f)
```

The idea is that the class method handles the work of calling `json.load` and passing the resulting key/value pairs to `__init__`, which is automatically generated to set the desired fields. `__post_init__` takes care of converting the
`None` values provided by the JSON object into "real" defaults.

Comment: Why do you provide types for all the fields? I do not understand the reasoning for this. I don't program a lot of Python, but mostly C and I thought that Python was mostly not staticly typed.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed. Type annotations can be used to support a level of static type checking by external tools.  Here, though, they are primarily intended to signal to the `dataclass` decorator that the annotated-though-possibly-undefined names are to be used in constructing various methods like `__init__`, `__eq__`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to have an `__init__` in your class to create a class instance with the values inside the json file.

Just have a `@classmethod` to do a load from a json file into a class instance, like so:

```py
import json

class Profile:
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_file):
        for key, value in json.load(open(json_file)).items():
            setattr(cls, key, value)
        return cls
```

Now you can create an instance like this:

```py
profile = Profile.from_json('/path/to/file.json')
profile._email  # --> "john@baker.com"
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I have one question though: What if I also need to be able to populate that object's fields via another method? E.G. in one case, the user provides them via CLI and in the second case, they load them from the json file? Maybe I turn the user input directly into json and then parse from there?

Comment: @the_endian you can just create another alternative constructor. Note, the above implementation is **incorrect**. it sets the attribtues *on the class object*. This method should *instantiate a profile object* and initialize it from the JSON (note, your original approach *works*, or the alternative one in the comments: `Profile(**json.load(file))` would do as well, or even the one in this answer except applied to an actual instance, and not the class